# How to expand textarea to fill up page

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I had a very simple html page with a top bar and a textarea. I want the textarea to fill up the height left by the top bar. It needs to adjust automatically after resizing.

E.g.

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="top" />
  <textarea id="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff but I always end up with two scrollbars (one for the textarea and one for the body).

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried? You might have been on the right path but we won't know, and that wastes everybodies time

Comment: In general, the 'overflow' property controls the appearance of scrollbars, but as @SterlingArcher said, let us know what you've tried - and importantly in this case what browsers you are targeting.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed height top bar you can use position absolute on your text area to fill the remaining area like so:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#top {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #333399;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    resize: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">Top</div>
<textarea id="text">Textarea</textarea>
```

Comment: This gives two scrollbars when textarea has large enough text.

Comment: This does not happen in Chrome. All I get is a vertical scroll bar on the textarea when there is enough text. What browser is this occurring on for you?

Comment: Chrome. I filled up the textarea and hit the two bars.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot recreate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, maybe this can help [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emrevera/kk1ej8h6/) but then again I'm not sure if this is what you want, and its just a raw version of what I think you might be asking. Also notice that there are some declarations that can be avoided if you already have a reset for your css

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <div id="top"></div>
    <textarea id="text"></textarea>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body,html{
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.content{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}
#top{
    height:50px;
    background-color:#CCC;
    width:100%;
}
#text{
    height:85%;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#999;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to set the topbar size explicitly. I want it to grow freely and text-div to occupy 100% of the remaining.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

JS:

```
totalCalc();
function totalCalc()
{
    var bodyHeight = $("body").outerHeight(true);
    var topHeight = $("#top").outerHeight(true);
    var txtareaHeight = bodyHeight - topHeight - 10;
    $('#text').attr("style", "height:" + txtareaHeight + "px");
}
$(window).resize(totalCalc);
```

CSS:

```
*{margin:0; padding:0; font-family:Tahoma; font-size:12px; color:#333;}
html, body{height:100%; overflow:hidden;}
#top{padding:10px;}
#text{margin:0 10px;}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karthik_Dev/e63du34z/)